# Get all values from table and reuse them to create rows in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table (People) with columns (id, name, year). Is there any way I can get all the ids ( `SELECT id FROM people` ) and use them for creating new rows in other table (people_id, additional_info). I mean that for every id in table People I want to add new row in other table containing the id and some additional information. Maybe something like for-loop is needed here ?

Comment: Is there any relation between additional_info? are they both connected with id?

Comment: It depends on how you want to supply the extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, usually you have information on a person and write one record with this information. It makes litte sense to write empty records for all persons. Moreover, when it's just one record per person, why not simply add an information column to the people table?

Anyway, you can create mock records thus:

```
insert into people_info (people_id, additional_info)
select id, null from people;
```

Comment: how should it looks like if the additional_info have to be select from third table ?

Comment: Well, if it's already in a table, why copy it to another? But okay, if you want to do that, simply change the query, e.g.: `select p.id, t.info from people p left join third_table t on t.people_id = p.id`;

Comment: and what if there`s no relation between these two tables and the third one ?

Comment: So the third table has just *one* row with information you want to apply to all persons? Otherwise, which third table row to join with which person?

Comment: Yes the information I want from the third table is the same for all the rows. I need to get one id from the third table but I want to get it on some condition

Comment: Like so: `select p.id, t.info from people p join third_table t on t.id = 1234`?

Comment: Lets say in third table we have (id, name) and there is no relation between the third table and the other two i want additionalInfo to be : `select id from third_table where name = "something"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123681/discussion-between-thorsten-kettner-and-user5783530).

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into targetTable (id, additional_info)
select id,'additionalinfo' from PEOPLE
```

No for loop is needed, Just use the above query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT ... SELECT syntax for MySQL to insert the rows into people_info table (documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)).

e.g.

```
insert into people_info(...)
select (...) from people; <and posibly other tables>
```

Comment: how should it looks like if the additionalInfo is also get from table, but it`s third table

Comment: In that case, you can use join statement to join multiple table.

Comment: what if there`s no relation between these two tables and the third one ?